# Showing fields from different bundles that are related

Tags: views

I'm trying to display the fields of one content type while searching on another content type. More specifically... here is my situation:

I have a view based on an index with fields in Organism and fields in mRNA.

Content type: Organism
Fields: order, common name, genus, species

Content type: mRNA
Fields: description, scientific name (Genus species)

I set up search filters for description, order, common name, scientific name. The result should look something like:
link to mRNA page
order | scientific name | common name
description

However, if I actually search by description, nothing shows up for order and common name. I feel like this is the result of an outer join of the two content types.

How would I "inner join" organism on scientific name? I've tried looking into EntityReference module but it seems like I would have to manually fill in the entity reference for every mRNA page I have... which isn't what I want.

Thanks

Comment: What is the connection between Organism nodes and mRNA nodes based on which you want to "inner join"? Are genus and species taxonomies?

Comment: The genus and species in Organism should be the same as scientific name in mRNA. Genus and species are not listed anywhere in Administration->Structure->Taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using the Views Field View module. It basically gives you the ability make a subquery inside a view using a subview.

First I created a new index on organism with an aggregated field called Scientific Name that combines Genus and species. Then I made a view on that index with a contextual filter with Scientific Name (display empty text when filter value not in url; specify validation criteria).
Then I made the other view which uses the previously made view as a subview.

Well here's an intro tutorial for the module anyways: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-field-view/